# Create a list from other lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list `{a,b,c,d}` and a second list where is how many times the elements of the first list repeat `{1,4,2,6}` (the order is according with the first list). Then I need to create a third list with this information: `{a,b,b,b,b,c,c,d,d,d,d,d,d}`. What can I do?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe. Anyway: `Flatten[MapThread[Table, {{a, b, c, d}, {1, 4, 2, 6}}]]`

Comment: very closly related / possible duplicate: [Convert frequency counts to long notation in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45931/125)

Answer (score 1):

```
Catenate @ MapThread[ConstantArray, {{a, b, c, d}, {1, 4, 2, 6}}]
```

> `{a, b, b, b, b, c, c, d, d, d, d, d, d}`

Comment: I'm leaving my answer but please vote for [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45932/19530) instead (ht kglr).

Comment: `Catenate` not needed. `Flatten@MapThread[ConstantArray, {{a, b, c, d}, {1, 4, 2, 6}}]` works. Has advantage of working in older versions without `Catenate`.