# Creating a new data list

Tags: list-manipulation, data

Let's consider the following data set

```
data = {{1,3},{-2,4},{5,2}};
```

with pairs of $(x,y)$, where the $y$ values indicate the count of the $x$ values. Now I want to create a new list containing only the $x$ values with the corresponding count. For example, in the above example, the new list should contain

```
data2 = {1,1,1,-2,-2,-2,-2,5,5}
```

that is three times 1, four times -2 and two times 5.

Any suggestions?

Comment: duplicate?: [Convert frequency counts to long notation in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45931/125)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ConstantArray @@@ data // Flatten
```

> {1, 1, 1, -2, -2, -2, -2, 5, 5}